# Access frequency limitation for reading PMCCNTR_EL0?

Tags: c, arm, profiling, perf

I am using `perf_event_open` in my c profiling app to leverage perf in getting event data. In order to improve performance, I am reading the hardware registers directly by following the [Perf Userspace PMU Hardware Counter Access documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/arch/arm64/perf.html#perf-userspace-pmu-hardware-counter-access) to read the PMU register directly using the `mrs` instruction.

I use the following code:

```
static struct perf_event_attr attr;
attr.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
attr.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES;
attr.exclude_kernel = 1;
attr.exclude_hv = 1;
attr.config1 = 3; // user access enabled

int fd = syscall(SYS_perf_event_open, &attr, 0, -1, -1, 0);

ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

// Code where we want to measure performance. At certain points we call read_register_directly()

ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
close(fd);
```

```
uint64_t read_register_directly() {
  uint64_t value = 0;
  asm volatile("mrs %0, PMCCNTR_EL0 " : "=r" (value));
  return value;
}
```

The above code to read the register directly works properly with the perf configuration. The problem is that after ~25 reads of the register I am getting an "illegal instruction" error, though I'm not sure why.

- Could it be an access frequency limitation?
- Or some ARM security mechanism?
- Perhaps some concurrency issue? Though I tested this by using a semaphore to lock read_register_directly() to ensure a single read at a time, and the issue still persisted.

I looked through the ARM docs for [PMCCNTR_EL0](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0595/2021-03/AArch64-Registers/PMCCNTR-EL0--Performance-Monitors-Cycle-Count-Register) and some other resources but I haven't found anything which explains this illegal instruction error.

Comment: When you get an illegal instruction exception, is the trapping instruction the MRS in your inline asm block?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli That is correct. The only instruction is the PMCCNTR_EL0 mrs call above

Comment: What processor / hypervisor are you on? If you know the exact model it may help. A [mre] (where you wrap the code in a `main` and add the headers so it's easy to compile and run) would also help.

Comment: FYI, in userspace, under Linux, you can use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,...)` It will map the counter into userspace via a `VDSO` so no syscall, so about as fast as rolling your own. It does _whatever_ is needed because the kernel injects the model specific/correct code. You can disassemble the function and use it as a guide if needed. But, I just use the function. I've benchmarked it and is is fast enough. It also converts the counter tick value to nanoseconds.

Comment: @CraigEstey A call through VDSO or a fetch from memory is probably still too slow for stuff like microbenchmarks, performance counters are more or less the only option in such cases.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli It's been 3+ years since I worked on this, so my memory may be a bit fuzzy. IIRC, the kernel must _enable_ userspace access to the counter. I found this: https://github.com/jerinjacobk/armv8_pmu_cycle_counter_el0 which seems to confirm this. So, we should call `clock_gettime` at least once to have the kernel do the enabling. Then, disasemble the code to get the correct `mrs` et. al. instructions. This _must_ be done under `gdb` because the code is injected, so static disassembly (e.g. `objdump`) won't work

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Caveat: again, IIRC on all of this. The overhead on `clock_gettime` is _really_ small (e.g. 10-50 ns?). In my code, I looped on `clock_gettime` and was able to get the time for function itself. If the processor is relatively modern (e.g. `armv7` arch compliant), then we can use `PMCCNTR_EL0`. And, the VDSO code will use this. But, on older/lesser models, there was _no_ such direct userspace access? So, the kernel would I/O map the kernel register somehow and the code would access a special memory location?????

Comment: @CraigEstey ah, that is interesting now, could be. I guess it's worth looking at the VDSO code with a debugger to see if the "good" instruction is there. Seems weird though that OP would manage to read that register and then all of a sudden get a SIGILL, that I still don't know about.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I am on an arm64 v8a processor. It's just incredibly odd that the register is readable then, at a certain point, becomes unreadable. I'll spend some time today to create a minimal reproducible example to cut out the fat from my current test to narrow anything down. I appreciate both of your thoughts!

Comment: @Kron What OS are you using? Linux (what version)?

Comment: Real hardware or emulated (e.g. qemu)? Also, there are different ARMv8a processors, do you know the exact model? `cat /proc/cpuinfo` should give it to you.

Comment: I've tried on a couple different sets of hardware, all with the same result.
I've pinpointed the issue to being related to newly spun up threads. If we attempt to read the register from the same thread that the perf fd was created on, we have no problems. But when we try to read the register from a different thread, the exception occurs. 
I'm a bit confused why there would be a thread limitation when PMU register read permissions are based on perf_user_access. I don't know much about thread specific access, but could this be a limitation? I'd think all user level threads would have access...

Comment: @Kron I've been looking at some kernel source. Try putting an `isb` instruction before (comment: _This isb() is required to prevent that the counter value is speculated_) and after your `mrs` (comment: _This isb() is required to prevent that the seq lock is speculated._).

Comment: @Kron After looking at more kernel source, specifically the source for the injected vdso, it does two things; (1) `isb` (2) `mrs r1,cntvct_el0` This jogged my memory as _now_ I remember the disassembly to use `cntvct_el0` See: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0595/2021-12/AArch64-Registers/CNTVCT-EL0--Counter-timer-Virtual-Count-register

Comment: @CraigEstey The attr.inherit flag allow child threads access to read the register. So setting that and combining that with the `isb` instruction did the trick. Thanks so much for the help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was ultimately due to the attributes passed in the `perf_event_open` system call. The thread that made the system call was able to read the register directly, but other threads were resulting in "Illegal Instruction" error.

There is a `perf_event_attr` flag `inherit` which allows the user to profile all threads in a process instead of just the thread executed by `perf_event_open`. So in the above code I added two things to fix the code flow:

- `attr.inherit = 1;`
- `asm volatile("isb;");`  after reading the PMU register