# How to return CPU cycle count from register on arm64 in C using asm? (Apple M2)

Tags: c, arm64

I found on [ARM's website](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0595/2021-03/AArch64-Registers/PMCCNTR-EL0--Performance-Monitors-Cycle-Count-Register) that the `PMCCNTR_EL0` register holds the processor's cycle count value. But in order to access it `FEAT_PMUv3` must be implemented. But I am unable to access the register. Does Apple restrict accessing the register?

I need to count the number of cycles to benchmark a function:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
  c1 = get_cycle_count();
  function_to_benchmark();
  c2 = get_cycle_count();
  count_array[i] = c2 - c1;
}
```

I would like for the function `get_cycle_count()` to return the uint64 value of `PMCCNTR_EL0` using assembly within my C program.

I found [this](https://lemire.me/blog/2023/03/21/counting-cycles-and-instructions-on-arm-based-apple-systems/) C++ implementation, but am unable to replicate it for C.

Comment: For a nearly exact issue, see: [Access frequency limitation for reading PMCCNTR_EL0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77093320/5382650) You need an `isb` instruction. Note that the OS kernel must _enable_ access to the count register before a userspace program can access it directly.

Comment: Apple Silicon does not support `FEAT_PMUv3`. They use proprietary performance monitors.

Comment: @Siguza Are there other ways to use their proprietary performance monitors?

Comment: @Kolja it seems XNU provides an abstraction layer over this and exports it to userland via a bunch of `kpc.*` sysctls. And then there's the private kperf.framework that wraps over that, presumably providing a more stable API? [This file](https://github.com/lemire/Code-used-on-Daniel-Lemire-s-blog/blob/master/2023/03/21/performancecounters/apple_arm_events.h#L117-L121) has a reverse engineered header for that framework. And on Asahi Linux, `perf stat` supposedly uses it by default, since the Asahi team wrote a kernel driver for Apple's custom PMU (but I'm not sure where that is in the source).

Comment: @Siguza Thanks! I had read that file and [this file](https://github.com/lemire/Code-used-on-Daniel-Lemire-s-blog/blob/master/2021/03/24/m1cycles.cpp) and honestly it's Greek to me. Took me long enough to understand that the functions were not defined there linked in the kernel library, which should be here `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/kperf.framework/Versions/A/kperf` but I have no file called `kperf` there. I probably misunderstood something. Is there a simple way to scrape only a cycle counter from the linked page?

Answer (score 1):

The following example shows how to get a system register's value using inline assembly in C:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    uint64_t value;
    asm("isb; mrs %0, CNTVCT_EL0" : "=r"(value));
    printf("CNTVCT_EL0 = 0x%016lX\n", value);
}
```

Replace `CNTVCT_EL0` with `PMCCNTR_EL0` in your case to move the desired value into `value`.

Another thing to consider is that the system can restrict access to this register, as specified in the pseudocode of the [datasheet](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0595/2021-03/AArch64-Registers/PMCCNTR-EL0--Performance-Monitors-Cycle-Count-Register). I don't know how this behaves on macOS, since I don't have such a system to test.

Comment: See the link I added to the top comments. The solution needs an `isb` instruction because arm CPUs will _speculatively_ fetch CPU registers.