# How does perf correlate hardware events with PMU registers?

Tags: c, arm, profiling, perf

I have programmatically set up perf in such a way to allow for direct reading of PMU registers by following [perf docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/arch/arm64/perf.html#perf-userspace-pmu-hardware-counter-access) and the [ARM register summary](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100026/0100/performance-monitor-unit/pmu-register-summary).

Below is how I have set up perf to configure the CPU Cycle count hardware event:

```
static struct perf_event_attr attr;
attr.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
attr.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES;
attr.exclude_kernel = 1;
attr.exclude_hv = 1;
attr.config1 = 3; // user access enabled to read PMU counter directly
int fd = syscall(SYS_perf_event_open, &attr, 0, -1, -1, 0);
```

Then I read the event value via a mrs command to the PMU Cycle Count register directly:

```
uint64_t value=0;
asm volatile("isb");
asm volatile("mrs %0, PMCCNTR_EL0   " : "=r" (value));
```

As my next step I would like to expand this to read other hardware counters via PMU registers. For instance, if I configure perf to enable the `PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_REFERENCES` event, is there a PMU register I can read directly to get the cache references count?

Comment: Follow the links and comments in [Access frequency limitation for reading PMCCNTR_EL0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77093320/5382650) You need an `isb` instruction when reading `PMCCNTR_EL0` because arm registers are fetched _speculatively_

Comment: Yeah, I ommitted that in my initial post but I do have the `isb` instruction call. I am focused on reading other perf hardware events by reading PMU registers directly.